# How to delete application from iTunesConnect permanently so it can't be restored later?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Is there are way to completely remove an application from iTunesConnect, including even builds. There is two option for deletion:

There is an option (after app is removed from sale), in App Information section, that says: "Remove App".

Now, that doesn't really removes an app. The app can be restored. Also, all builds are still there.

Is there some way, to delete an app for real?

Comment: First google result: https://help.swiftic.com/hc/en-us/articles/201709211-Delete-Your-App-from-the-Apple-App-Store

Comment: I am aware of all that, thanks @KrishnaKumar I know that SKU can't be used, or bundle id. And what is a difference between removing from sale, or app "deletion". My question was, can app be really deleted, so it can't be restored.

Comment: as far as I know you can't delete a bundle identifier and recreate one with the same name, you need to use a new one for a new app.

Comment: @KrishnaKumar Yeah... But its not just about bundle id. I am talking about whole app, whole app information. Builds, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not 100% possible. You can remove all the metadata and screenshots, but there is currently no way to delete uploaded builds on [App Store Connect](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev28d17ed35).

> WARNING: If you remove an app, you will lose ownership of the app name. Removed apps can only be restored if the name is not currently in use by another developer account. In addition, the SKU can’t be reused in the same organization and if you’ve uploaded a build, your bundle ID can’t be reused.

Theoretically you can "reserve" the app name with another developer account and prevent the old account from restoring the app, but I would not bet on that as there are ways to get the [app name back](https://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/itunes/appnamenotices/).

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I tried and I was able to reatore it right few days after. All builds were there though. So restore was 100% identical as before "deletion".